# How to extend SimpleCV with GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, wxpython, simplecv

I am trying to write a simple application in **Python** which uses **SimpleCV for computer vision** and is **controlled by some very simple GUI**.

My problem is that while pure OpenCV has it's own HighGUI, SimpleCV uses pygame, thus I don't know how can I extend it to make use of OpenCV's HighGUI or any other kind of minimalistic GUI.

All I would need is a very simple slider or possibly some buttons.

For just sliders I think we can just use OpenCV's HighGUI. But **how do I get HighGUI to work with SimpleCV?**

For buttons, did anyone try anything **to combine SimpleCV with GTK+ or wxPython** or anything else?

Can you share some **simple code which uses SimpleCV and a very basic control interface?** (say one slider or a button)

*Note: It doesn't have to be in the same window, it's perfect in separate windows (say SimpleCV video loop running in it's own window while there is a control panel in a separate window).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have been able to combine Gtk and SimpleCV successfully.

https://github.com/jayrambhia/image-gtk

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/opencv-with-pygtk/

Example:

```
from SimpleCV import *
from imagegtk import DisplayImage

im = Image("Lenna")
image = im.toRGB.getBitmap()

d = DisplayImage(title="iamgegtk")

label = gtk.Label("Lenna")
d.box.pack_start(label,False,False,0)

but1 = gtk.Button("Quit")
but1.connect("clicked",d.leave_app)
d.box.pack_end(but1,False,False,2)

d.show(image)
```